# Text in panel body is not showing in rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

What need is in script in panel body text to be shown in rows for every data in ng-repeat. On left to be data.name and right to be icon. With current code data is not showing on separate rows, it is messy.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="field_renderer.html">
                    <div  class="col-md-6" ng-repeat-start="data in data.children">
                        <div class="row">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="{{data.name}}" ng-model="data.isSelected">
                            {{data.name}}
                        </label>
                        <span ng-if="data.children.length > 0">
                            <i class="pull-right glyphicon" data-ng-click="data.showDetails = !data.showDetails"
                               ng-class="{'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !data.showDetails, 'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-minus': data.showDetails}"></i>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="data.showDetails" ng-include="'field_renderer.html'"></div>
                </script>
                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div ng-repeat-start="data in reportsvm.filters" class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading clickable" data-ng-click="reportsvm.showDetails(data)">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a href="">{{data.name}}</a>
                                <i ng-class="{'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !data.showDetails, 'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-minus': data.showDetails}"></i>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body small" ng-if="data.showDetails" ng-repeat-end ng-include="'field_renderer.html'"></div>
                </div>
```

Here is screnshot of how it is looking.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see for location that two checkboxes I need to be one after another in separate rows. Also in Program i need to be in separate rows and in each row that icon to be on right.

**UPDATE - CURRENT SOLUTION**

```
 <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr ng-if="data.name === 'Location'">
                                <td class="noBorder" colspan="2">
                                    <button data-ng-click="reportsvm.changeLocation(data, true)" data-ng-class="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                        Regions</button>
                                    <button data-ng-click="reportsvm.changeLocation(data, false)" data-ng-class="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
                                        State/Territory</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-start="data in data.children">
                                <td class="noBorder">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{data.name}}" ng-change="reportsvm.changeValue(data)" ng-model="data.isSelected">
                                        {{data.name}}
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="noBorder">
                                    <span ng-if="data.children.length > 0">
                                        <i class="pull-right glyphicon" data-ng-click="data.showDetails = !data.showDetails"
                                           ng-class="{'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !data.showDetails, 'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-minus': data.showDetails}"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="data.showDetails">
                                <td class="noBorder" ng-include="'field_renderer.html'"></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Your styles are crucial here, make sure your `.row` has no floating assigned, to be `display: block`, also add `overflow: hidden` which will force clearing. You cannot get an accurate answer without posting relevant css.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense. You try to create a new checkbox for every column.
Bootstrap tries to fill in the space for col-md-6 (2-column layout).

```
 <div  class="col-md-6" ng-repeat-start="data in data.children">
```

One solution would be to put the *ng-repeat* in the row element:

```
<div  class="col-md-6">
   <div class="row" ng-repeat-start="data in children>
     <!--rest of the code ....-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer will try it later. For now I resolved this with adding one simple table.